# Laravel 5.5 - Load balancer gives error message the page has expired due to inactivity

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, laravel-5.5

I'm using the latest version of Laravel 5.5 with AWS. I have created a load balancer and two Amazon EC2 instances. The page works as expected only the registration or login does not work. The error message "The page has expired due to inactivity." is displayed. The `SESSION_DRIVER` is set to database. On every instance I've executed the following commands:

```
php /var/www/html/artisan cache:clear
php /var/www/html/artisan config:clear
php /var/www/html/artisan route:clear
php /var/www/html/artisan view:clear
```

Any clue what might be wrong?

What else did I try? Set the SESSION_DOMAIN to null, localhost. I also switched the SESSION_DRIVER back from database to file.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I have 2 forms, 1 works without any hitches, other doesn't. They work fine if i run them individually without Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed by doing this

**Method 01**

go to login page and registration page. And after the `<form>` tag add this

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

**Method 02**

If no luck use this

```
composer dumpautoload;
```

---

> **FYI**: you can clear cache by **`php artisan route:clear ;php artisan cache:clear`** by running this along with **`composer dumpautoload`** is enaugh.

Comment: csrf_field is already below the <form> tag. This is default since Laravel 5.5.

Comment: use dumpautoload and restart the project

Comment: composer dumpautoload returns 'Generating autoload files'. Result is still the same. I have this issue btw on every form or page I use.. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Needed to set the SESSION_DOMAIN= in the .env. localhost is not sufficient in this situation, but the full domain name was required.